# Fundamental matrix of shifted linear periodic system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions, stability-theory

Let's say we have linear system $\frac{dx}{dt} = A(t)x(t)$, where $A(t)$ is a periodic matrix, $x(t)$ a vector, and the associated fundamental matrix is $\Phi(t)$ such that $\Phi(0)=Identity$ . What can we say about the fundamental matrix of the shifted system $\frac{dx}{dt} = A(t+s)x(t)$ where $s$ is not equal to the period of $A$? How do the Lypanov exponents of the two systems relate?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a linear system
$$\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t)$$
the solution is given by $x(t)=\Phi(t)x(0)$, where
$$\Phi(t)=\exp({\int_0^tA(\tau)d\tau})$$
So for the shifted system,
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = A(t+s)x(t)$$
the associated fundamental matrix is
$$\begin{align}\Phi(t)&=\exp({\int_0^tA(\tau+s)d\tau})=\exp({\int_s^{t+s}A(v)dv})\\
&=\exp({-\int_0^s A(v)dv+\int_0^{t+s}A(v)dv})=
\Phi(s)^{-1}\Phi(t+s)\end{align}$$
So the solution of the system is given by
$$x(t)=\Phi(s)^{-1}\Phi(t+s)x(0)$$
and then you can relate the Lyapunov exponents of the two systems.

Comment: Sorry to say, but formula via matrix exponent [doesn't work](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/ExpMatrix.pdf) (see p. 6). It works for constant matrix $A(t)$; there is an [ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) however.

Comment: You are right @Evgeny . The necessary condition for that formula is: $$\int_0^{s}A(v)dv\int_0^{t+s}A(v)dv=\int_0^{t+s}A(v)dv\int_0^{s}A(v)dv$$